# PHP page to PDF with object oriented websites

Tags: php, pdf, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get my shopping cart items to a pdf to create an invoice

I have url which shows the invoice in html/css like this:

```
index.php?module=checkout&view=topdf
```

If I want to get the content of that page to use in mPDF or other pdf libraries using file_get_contents or cURL it doesn't give any content because the url is not an actual file on the server

How can I fix this? I work with templates and don't know how can I export the current php page to a html page

Answer (score 1):

I used TCPDF for something similar. Getting the formatting right is a bit of a pain but once you've got that it's a really good bit of work.

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: Do you have an example that uses templates and not an actual topdf.php file?

Comment: Not to hand but I can try and have a look a bit later on for you. Are you using a shopping cart system?